# spring HATEOAS links issue for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: nginx, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I am using `Spring HATEOAS` in my web application. My application runs behind a `Nginx` webserver. I am sending following url with HTTPS header

GET    `https://national.usa.com/testapp-rest/api/user/654rtrtet-5grt-fgsdf-dfgs-765ytrtsdhshfgsh/newAuthentication`

```
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headersview sourceAccess-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with, Accept, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-aliveContent-Type:application/json
Pragma:No-cacheServer:XXX/1.6.0
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding:chunkedRequest Headers
view sourceAccept:application/json, text/plain, */*Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
```

But when I see response headers, I see HATEOAS links are only returning  HTTP. how to fixed this issue? Please guide.

```
"links: [{rel: "self",…}]0: {rel: "self",…}href: "http://national.usa.com
/testapp-rest/api/user/5435fdsg-45gfdgag-rewtdf43434-43543fsd "rel
```

Edit: Yes I using following code to create links

```
resource.add(ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn(TestController.class).getStudentResponse(response.getStudentId())).withSelfRel());
```

Comment: Is it a demo URL you posted? I am receiving a 404. Do you run your application behind a webserver like Apache Httpd or Nginx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments your application runs behind a webserver. In this case Nginx.

You are using some sort of

```
linkTo(methodOn(MyController.class).myMethod(name)).withSelfRel());
```

to generate links. In this case take a look at [`ControllerLinkBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/0.19.0.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.java#L187-L231). As you can see in line 190 Spring HATEOAS builds a link based on the current request.
In addition, request header `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-Ssl` are queried and used if available.

That is what you missed to configure in order to build proper links with Spring HATEOAS.

Because you complain that only `https` is missing in your links, Nginx already sets `X-Forwarded-For` but skips `X-Forwarded-Proto`. I assume that Nginx and your application communicate over `http` otherwise you wouldn't have trouble.
You can ignore `X-Forwarded-Ssl`. It is only relevant if Nginx and your application talking over `https`. In that case you wouldn't see any issue either.

Below you find a complete Nginx `location` block for reference. `X-Forwarded-Proto` has been set to `https` in order to inform the proxied system that links have to contain `https` in any URLs (only if backend system processes aforedmetnioned request header).

```
location /yourapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/yourapp;
    proxy_redirect default;
    proxy_set_header  Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
}
```

For further reading please consult Nginx documentation for the [`http_proxy_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Comment: NGINX noob here: why not `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;`?