# SPRING HATEOS LINKS (HTTPS vs HTTP)

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I have a simple rest service which returns the response when a GET operation is performed along with the HATEOS links. When the service is deployed on the server and is accessed through  a load balancer url (Https), the links section contains the url with "http" instead of "https". Any example solution/code for this particular scneario would help me.

For Example:

If a GET operation is performed by using the url(https://servicename.example.com) then I would expect the same url to be in the links section. But I receive something like below.

Response Body:

```
       {
      "fieldA": null,
      "fieldB": null,
      "links": [
        {
         "rel": "self",
         "href": "http://servicename.example.com" // It has to be https
        }
      ]
     }
```

Below is the line of code that adds the links to the Rest Resource that will be exposed to the consumer.

```
 resource.getLinks().add(linkTo(methodOn(ExampleController.class).methodInExampleController(arg a, arg b)).withSelfRel());
```

The resource that is being exposed to the consumer extends another class"ResourceSupport" where a field called links is declared which is of type List.

Example of Resource class:

```
     imnport com.examplepackage.ResourceSupport

     public SampleResource extends ResourceSupport{

        private String fieldA,

        private String fieldB,

        //setters and getters

          }
```

Example of the class where HATEOS Links are declared

```
      import org.springframework.hateoas.Identifiable;
      import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;

      public ResourceSupport implements Identifiable<Link>{

            @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
            private final List<Link> links = new ArrayList();

            @JsonProperty("links")
            public List<Link> getLinks() {
             return this.links;
              }
          }
```

SPRING HATEOS version: spring-hateos0.24.0.RELEASE

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the post. Please let me know if it makes more sense.

Comment: Not really. I understood what you were asking, you still haven't provided the code and config that *leads* to that outcome.

Comment: This is my first question here in stack overflow. So please do excuse. Updated my POST again. Please take a look

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942648/spring-hateoas-links-issue-for-http-and-https?

Comment: I did. That post talks about a location block of Nginix server which is used to handle incoming requests for various resources. I think adding the required headers (X-Forwarded-proto, X-Forwarded-ssl)  on the proxy server may do the job. But is there any way where we can handle this use case in our application code itself?

Comment: The more you manually interfere, the less Spring is helping and the more likely you are to introduce bugs. If you force HTTPS, the links will be wrong for HTTP requests during local development and testing, for example. It's also worth noting that *other* things might not be working if the proxy isn't adding the right headers.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring HATEOAS links issue for HTTP and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942648/spring-hateoas-links-issue-for-http-and-https)